# Does Regulation D limit 6 transactions per account, or 6 combined?

Tags: united-states, regulation

If I have multiple savings accounts, do each account get the 6 transaction limit imposed by [Regulation D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_D_(FRB)), or am I limited to 6 transactions for all accounts combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction is per account, not per person.  For example, if two people co-own an account, they still get only 6 transactions per month, not 12.  Likewise, if you own two accounts, each one still gets 6 transactions.

In any case, you should read the terms of each of your accounts to see whether your institution even cares (i.e. imposes some sort of penalty) when you exceed these limits.